# MVC Client side validation: At least one of two textboxes must be filled

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I need to create a validator  where at least either FirstName or LastName must be filled.

```
public class Person
{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

}
```

I want user to provide at least, either first name or last name. Providing both shouldn't be a prob.
This is currently what I have at view

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@using(Html.BeginForm("AddPerson","Person",FormMethod.Post))
{

    <div class="label">First Name</div>
    <div class="input-block-level">@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.FirstName)</div>
    <br/>
    <div class="label">Last Name</div>
    <div class="input-block-level">@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.LastName)</div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Submit</button>
}
```

What should I do to validate the form on the client side so that error is thrown when at least one textbox is not filled??

Comment: you can write javascript function to check that

Comment: check this solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247748/mvc3-validation-require-one-from-group#answer-7248203

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn-primary" onclick="javascript: return checkform()" >

function checkform()
{
var fname= $('#FirstName').val();
var lname= $('#LastName').val();
if(fname=="" && lname=="")
  {
    alert("Enter either first name or last name") ;
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to have custom validation. But if i can't find solution, i shall use this. Till then i'lll vote it up.

Comment: Doesn't work, i submitted form with empty firstname and lastname and it still forwarded to post method of the controller

Comment: have you check values of `fname` and `lname`

Comment: check edited answer...i have written format of javascript incorrect

Comment: it works, i get message and when i click Ok i get forwarded to post method of conrtolelr, how can i make it stay on same view and not forward to post method till something is filled