# At least one radio button should be checked through custom validation in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I am new to MVC framework. I have 2 radio buttons and i want at least one should be checked. I want to do it through custom validation, need help?

The field is "usWorkPermit":

My View code:

```
Do you have US Work Visa ?
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.usWorkPermit,"True") Yes I have
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.usWorkPermit, "False") No I don't
```

My Model code:

```
[UsWorkPermitValidation]
public Boolean usWorkPermit { get; set; }
```

My Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Models.JobApplication jobApplication)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    }
    return View();
}
```

I created the custom validator which is incomplete. I want to ask how i can force at least one radio button to be checked ??

```
public class UsWorkPermitValidation : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // check at least one radio button is checked.
    }
}
```

How to get values of each radio buttons on my custom validator? If i know then then i can easily do the checking ??

Comment: did you try using `[Required]`?

Comment: [Required] not working on my case.

Comment: as per the definition of "radio button", you don't want "at least one" radio button to be checked, you want "exactly one" radio button to be checked.  In other words, in a group of radio buttons, it is nonsensical to have two radio buttons checked.  That's what checkboxes are for.

Comment: @yogihosting: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247748/mvc3-validation-require-one-from-group)

Comment: @MikeNakis i want the radio button to be checked(there will be only one which can be checked, also during the page loading for the first time none of them is checked). I want to make sure user has to check them and i want to do it through custom validation.

Comment: basically i want to know how to loop through the values of each radio button in my custom validation class - "UsWorkPermitValidation" ? any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wasting time when people have already wasted time to make this easy for us. Try using unabtrusive js instead.

```
class UsWorkPermitValidation
{
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your error message")]
  public Boolean usWorkPermit { get; set; }
}
```

In your view.cshtml

```
@Html.Label("Yes, I've")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.usWorkPermit, "Yes")
@Html.Label("No, I don't Have")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.usWorkPermit, "No")
```

And add the reference of the following jquery scripts files within bundle/current view.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the snap of its run.

[image]

Comment: Because clientside validation can trivially be bypassed.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, It worked for me

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.usWorkPermit, true , new {@required = "true"}) //Yes I have
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.usWorkPermit, false) //No I don't
```

According to me, No need to use custom validator only for this