# Strongly Typed View Helper to Check Validation of a single property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, helper, strongly-typed-view

How do I check if a single property in my model has a validation error, from within my view?

I realise that I can do this, but it's not strongly typed so I'm concerned it's prone to errors:

```
@if (ViewData.ModelState["MyProperty"].Errors.Count() > 0)
{
    // Show validation error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
public static bool IsValidFor<TModel, TProperty>(this TModel model,
                                                 System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
                                                 ModelStateDictionary modelState)
{
    string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

    return modelState.IsValidField(name);
}
```

Usage:

```
if (!model.IsValidFor(x => x.MyProperty, ModelState)) 
{
    // Show validation error
}
```

Courtesy: this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14008604/244353)

Comment: Thank you!  I'm going to give this a go.  When I know it's right I'll mark it correct. :)