# Remove ModelState errors in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to remove model validation for some properties in a Model in ASP.Net MVC6.

I came across this post [Is there a strongly-named way to remove ModelState errors in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008561/is-there-a-strongly-named-way-to-remove-modelstate-errors-in-asp-net-mvc/36359386?noredirect=1#comment60338333_36359386)

which suggests using, ModelBindingHelper.ClearValidationStateForModel(Type, ModelStateDictionary, IModelMetadataProvider, string).

But I am unable to find any further help on this.

Can anyone please suggest a working example of removing a model property using ClearValidationStateForModel?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? You want to remove a model validation error for few properties ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a strongly-named way to remove ModelState errors in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008561/is-there-a-strongly-named-way-to-remove-modelstate-errors-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should remove the validation errors for the `Title` property of your `CreatePost` view model.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreatePost model)  
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      //to do : Save and return something
    }   
    ModelBindingHelper.ClearValidationStateForModel(model.GetType(),
                                              ModelState,MetadataProvider,"Title");        
    return View(model);
}
```

Also, `ModelState.ClearValidationState` will also work.

```
ModelState.ClearValidationState("Title");
```

EDIT : As per the comment, OP wants to exclude a certain property to be validated based on another property value. This should work fine.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreatePost model)   //CreatePost model
{
    if (model.Type == 1)
    {
        ModelBindingHelper.ClearValidationStateForModel(model.GetType(), 
                                                    ModelState, MetadataProvider, "Title");
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // to do : Do useful stuff and return something
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Both of these doesn't seem to work in ASP.Net MVC 6.

Below is how I am using it:

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreatePost model)  
{
   //I want to skip the validation for Title, so I added this line before checking ModelState.IsValid

    ModelBindingHelper.ClearValidationStateForModel(model.GetType(), ModelState,MetadataProvider,"Title");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      //to do : Save and return something
    }   
        
    return View(model);
}

Comment: What do you mean it does not work on MVC6 ? I just verified this in an MVC 6 project and it works fine (both dnx 451 and dnxcore50). Specifically what is not working for you ?

Comment: I have different properties in a model one of them is Type and Other is Duration, I want to skip validation of Duration if the selected type is 1 whereas I want to run the validation for all other types. In MVC5 ModelState.Remove("Duration"); before checking ModelState.IsValid was working, this doesnt seem to work in MVC 6. I also tried your suggested solution i.e. ModelState.ClearValidationState("Duration"); before checking ModelState.IsValid, but it does work the ModelState.IsValid is returned as fails. I have verified all other properties of the model have valid data.

Comment: It should work ! I just verified it. See my updated answer. The code i posted works fine for me in MVC 6. Project. Put a breakpoint and see whether it is going inside your if condition.

Comment: @Shyju    
I still use MVC 5 and I am trying to find the similar library for MVC 5. Where can I find out an open source for MVC 5? The link github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/… is just for MVC.Core.

Answer (score 2):

For new comers use

```
ModelState.ClearValidationState("propertyname");
ModelState.MarkFieldValid("propertyname");
```

If its nested object then use objectname.propertyname.

this works on ASP.Net Core 6.0

Answer (score 1):

[`ModelBindingHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Internal.ModelBindingHelper) is new to ASP.NET Core 2.0 / MVC6+

If you need to use against previous versions of .NET / ASP.NET, you can do the following per Simon_Weaver's answer on [Is there a strongly-named way to remove ModelState errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14008604/1366033):

> Here's my solution - a `RemoveFor()` extension method on `ModelState`, modelled after MVC HTML helpers:
>
> ```cs
> public static void RemoveFor<TModel>(this ModelStateDictionary modelState, 
>                                      Expression<Func<TModel, object>> expression)
> {
>     string expressionText = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
>
>     foreach (var ms in modelState.ToArray())
>     {
>         if (ms.Key.StartsWith(expressionText + "."))
>         {
>             modelState.Remove(ms);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> And here's how it's used:
>
> ```cs
> if (model.CheckoutModel.ShipToBillingAddress == true) 
> {
>     // COPY BILLING ADDRESS --> SHIPPING ADDRESS
>     ShoppingCart.ShippingAddress = ShoppingCart.BillingAddress;
>
>     // REMOVE MODELSTATE ERRORS FOR SHIPPING ADDRESS
>     ModelState.RemoveFor<SinglePageStoreModel>(x => x.CheckoutModel.ShippingAddress);
> }
>
> if (ModelState.IsValid) 
> {
>      // should get here now provided billing address is valid
> }
> ```

Comment: I do this, and I verified that `this.ModelState.Values.All( ms => ms.Errors.Count == 0 )` however `this.ModelState.IsValid == false`. Why?

Comment: @Dai you need to call `MarkFieldValid()` after `ClearValidationState()`. Otherwise the ValidationState is `Unvalidated` which results in `ModelState.IsValid = false`

Answer (score 1):

I needed for validation to have an exception for a single field in the VM

In the controller, I am doing:

```
if ("true" == Condition)
{
    ModelState.Remove("KeyName");
}
```

If "KeyName" was the only error in the ModelState, it will now be true

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{   
    // ModelState.IsValid is true now
}
```