# C# Linq to remove error item from modelstate not working

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to **remove** a particular error from c# **ModelState** using linq but not successful..

Linq not working/removing items but no error:

```
 ModelState.Values.ToList().ForEach(u =>
            {
                if (u.Errors.Any())
                {
                    u.Errors.ToList().RemoveAll(z =>
                        z.ErrorMessage == "Exceeded allowed chars");
                }
            });
```

Working one:

```
foreach (var s in ModelState.Values)
            {
                foreach (var e in s.Errors.ToList())
                {
                    if (e.ErrorMessage == "Exceeded allowed chars")
                        s.Errors.Remove(e);
                }
            }
```

Why the above linq not removing error item? what I'm missing?
Possible to avoid ToList() in linq to avoid performance penalty?

[image: Error while assigning errors to modelstate]

Comment: why `.ToList()`. Remove that then it should work. `ToList` creates a new list

Comment: without .ToList() it is IEnumerable type & you cant call RemoveAll()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove ModelState errors in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361095/remove-modelstate-errors-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: my requirement is different, dont want to remove a particular control/property related error always. But dynamically want to remove errors if it message equals "Exceeded allowed chars" for example.

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi, not the one I'm looking for. I have the solution & posted the same above. But want to know the mistake I have done in my LINQ above