# Jquery validation to require at least one field is selected for a filter?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

Can someone give me a Jquery example to enforce at least one field is selected.
My issue how do I check for items like checkbox and dropdownlists (default empty string)?
Note: using ASP.NET MVC3 C#

my code in the view:

```
 <fieldset  id="fieldset1" class="coolfieldset">
        <legend>Search/Contacts</legend>
        <div class="div-table">
        <div class="div-table-row">
            <div class="div-table-col">Reg Date:</div>
            <div class="div-table-col"><input id="regDateFrom" class="datepicker" name="regDateFrom" value="@regDateFrom" type="text" /> to <input id="regDateEnd" class="datepicker" value="@regDateEnd" name="regDateEnd" type="text" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="div-table-row">
            <div class="div-table-col">Profile Mod Date:</div>
            <div class="div-table-col"><input type="text" id="profileModDateFrom" class="datepicker" value="@profileModDateFrom"  name="profileModDateFrom" /> to <input id="profileModDateEnd" class="datepicker" value="@profileModDateEnd" name="profileModDateEnd" type="text" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="div-table-row">
            <div class="div-table-col">Last Name:</div>
            <div class="div-table-col"><input type="text" class="required_group"  id="lastName" name="lastName" value="@lastName" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="div-table-row">
            <div class="div-table-col"> First Name:</div>
            <div class="div-table-col"><input type="text" class="required_group"  id="firstName" name="firstName" value="@firstName"  /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="div-table-row">
            <div class="div-table-col"> Company:</div>
            <div class="div-table-col"> <input type="text" class="required_group"  id="companyname" name="companyname" value="@companyname" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="div-table-row">
            <div class="div-table-col">Publication:</div>
            <div class="div-table-col"> 
            @Html.DropDownList(
            "publication", 
                new SelectList(
                    ViewData["pubs"] as System.Collections.IEnumerable,
                    "PublicationID",
                    "PublicationFullName",
                    publication
                ),""
            )
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="div-table-row">
            <div class="div-table-col"> Country:</div>
            <div class="div-table-col"> 
             @Html.DropDownList(
            "country", 
                new SelectList(
               ViewData["countries"] as System.Collections.IEnumerable,
                   "Country",
                   "Country",
                    country
                ),""
            )
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="div-table-row">
            <div class="div-table-col">Client Only:</div>
            <div class="div-table-col"> <input type="checkbox" id="cisonly" name="cisonly" value="1" @bChecked />
        </div>
          <div class="div-table-row">
            <div class="div-table-col"><input id="search" name="search" type="submit" value="Search" /></div>
            <div class="div-table-col"></div>
        </div>
        </div>      
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: take a look here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816313/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation-group-of-inputs][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816313/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation-group-of-inputs

Answer (score 1):

To check if at least a checkbox is checked you could  use:

```
 if($('input:checkbox:checked').length > 0){
       //at least one checkbox checked
```

The same for radio buttons

```
 if($('input:radio:checked').length > 0){
       //at least one checkbox checked
```

Comment: It should be > 0, or >=1... It's +1 anyway

Comment: @Andre thanx that was what i intended to write! :)

Comment: Cool, what about all dropdownlist and all textbox?