# Validation general jQuery.Validate, similar to use "IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(...)"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I have a complex validation on a field that depends on other 3 fieldsthe validation on the server is simple because the method I use "Validate"

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
   // my validation
   if(complex_condition)
   {
       yield return new
               ValidationResult("my error", new List<string> {"field1"});
   }
}
```

But do not know how to do the same on the client. Could put the validation in the event "submit", but I would like the show as an error message in the field that I am validating, as if fired the required field validation.

Thank you.

**Edit: Solution after the response @DarinDimitrov:**

Javascript:

```
$.validator.addMethod('mycustomvalidation', function (value, element, parameters) {

    if (value.length < 6) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('mycustomvalidation', [], function (options) {
    options.rules['mycustomvalidation'] = {};

    for(var key in options.params) {
        options.rules['mycustomvalidation'][key] =  options.params[key];
    }

    options.messages['mycustomvalidation'] = options.message;
});
```

I can create a custom Data annotation:

Model:

```
[CustomClientValidation("mycustomvalidation", "value1", "value2", ErrorMessage="validacion propia")]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Data annotation:

```
public class CustomClientValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public CustomClientValidationAttribute(string validationType)
    {
        this.ValidationType = validationType;
    }

    public CustomClientValidationAttribute(string validationType, params object[] parameters)
        : this(validationType)
    {
        if (parameters != null && parameters.Count() > 0)
        {
            this.ValidationParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            var countParameters = parameters.Count();
            for (var index = 0; index < countParameters; index++)
            {
                this.ValidationParameters.Add(string.Format("parameter{0}", index), parameters[index]);
            }
        }
    }

    public string ValidationType { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<string, object> ValidationParameters { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule()
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
            ValidationType = this.ValidationType,
        };

        if (this.ValidationParameters != null)
        {
            foreach (var parameter in this.ValidationParameters)
            {
                rule.ValidationParameters.Add(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
            }
        }

        yield return rule;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Or with javascript:

```
$.validator.addMethod('mycustomvalidationii', function(value) {

    if (value.length < 6) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}, 'my custom validation');

$("#MyProperty").rules("add", "mycustomvalidationii");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a custom validation attribute that will implement the [IClientValidatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iclientvalidatable.aspx) interface and then register a custom adapter for the client validation. Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5817958/29407) that illustrates how you could write such custom validation attribute that will be capable of validating multiple dependent properties and also attach a custom client validation adapter to replicate the same validation logic on the client.

Comment: I found two ways to fix (one based on your answer), you can see the edit.