# Date and Time Display Format in ASP.NET MVC App

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, date

I want to Edit date as `"23/5/2017"` and time as `"03:53 PM"`. my model has Date `DisplayFormat` as `"{0:dd/M/yyyy}"` and time `DisplayFormat` as `"{0:hh:mm tt}"`

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[Display(Name = "Date")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/M/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime LogInDate { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[Display(Name = "Time In")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime LogInTime { get; set; }
```

View Code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LogInDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LogInDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LogInDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LogInTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LogInTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LogInTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the HTML for date:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date must be a date." data-val-required="The Date field is required." id="LogInDate" name="LogInDate" type="datetime" value="">
```

And HTML for time:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Time In must be a date." data-val-required="The Time In field is required." id="LogInTime" name="LogInTime" type="datetime" value="">
```

When I want to enter data, I get this error: [image]

Index page works fine:

[[image: Date/Time displays correctly]]

Also If I can get this sorted, can I use any of the Format Specifier (From Microsoft's **"Custom Date and Time Format Strings" Page**) in `DataFormatString` to display/edit the date/time as I need?

Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: `LogInTime` needs to be `TimeSpan`, not `DateTime`. And if you want client side validation for dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format, then you need to reconfigure the `$.validator`

Comment: Please refer to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872493/validating-time-only-input-in-asp-net-mvc-unobtrusive-validation)